# Python setup.py egg_info failed with spotdl

Tags: python, linux, debian

I'm trying to install the spotdl package with Debian linux. However, after many attempts of trying to get the package installed, and reading over many articles on this issue, I keep getting this error:
[image]

I cannot find any fix for this.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following commands hope it will work. You need to have Python 3.6.1 or above to install the package.

```
pip install -U spotdl
```

Or

```
sudo apt install ffmpeg
pip install spotdl
```

Comment: I've already tried those commands, and they didn't work before. However, I figured out that I need Python 3, in which I needed to get pip3, which then I did pip3 install, which worked. However, now I need FFmpeg (4.2), because 4.1 is too old. How can I get FFmpeg 4.2+?